# Set values on right side of ordered shuttle in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to set values from an object into an orderedShuttle.

I've tryed using `setValue()` and even iteraring a List and adding them one by one.
I just can't do it. How can I do such thing?

Here's what I have now:

```
Parametros_IndicadoresLoadAll pila = Parametros_IndicadoresLoadAll.getInstance(); //object with values to set
if(pila.getDc() != null && !pila.getDc().isEmpty())
    it1.setValue(pila.getDc());
if(pila.getUnidadeNegocio() != null && !pila.getUnidadeNegocio().isEmpty())
    it2.setValue(pila.getUnidadeNegocio());
if(pila.getCat() != null && !pila.getUnidadeNegocio().isEmpty())
    it3.setValue(pila.getCat());
if(pila.getSubCat() != null && !pila.getSubCat().isEmpty()) {
        sos1.setValue(pila.getSubCat()); //sos1 - my shuttle. getSubCat() returns a list
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a view object for constructing the shuttle.